# Map does not load centered when doing first search

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

Can anyone tell me why the map does not load centered the first time it loads? It works fine when I do a second search, but never loads up correctly the first time.

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var geocoder;
var currentAddress = 'placeholder';
var tabCount = 0;
var altRouteCount = 0;
var savedRoutes;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#message-container').hide (0);
  document.getElementById('sidebar').className = 'sidebar-hidden';
  // Keeps form pointAB from refreshing the page.
  $('#pointAB').on('submit', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });

  $('#tabs').tab();
  $('#tabs a').click( function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });

  $('#sidebar #togglebtn').click(toggleSidebar);
  $('#deletes').click(deleteTabs);
  $('#routeChange').click(function () {
        var index = $('#routeChange').data('route');
        index = (index+1)%altRouteCount;
        deleteTabs();
        printRoute (savedRoutes, index);
        $('#routeChange').data('route', index);
    });

  // Call Google Direction 
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  // Google Autocomplete
  var start_input = document.getElementById('start');
  var end_input = document.getElementById('end');
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.532980, -74.118551),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.895218, -73.735403)
  );

  // Bounds right now only restrict country
  var start_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((start_input),{
      // bounds: {sw:new google.maps.LatLng(40.895218, -73.735403), ne:new google.maps.LatLng(40.532980, -74.118551)},
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    }
  );
  var end_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((end_input),{
      // bounds: {sw:new google.maps.LatLng(40.895218, -73.735403), ne:new google.maps.LatLng(40.532980, -74.118551)},
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    }
  );
  start_autocomplete.setBounds(bounds);
  end_autocomplete.setBounds(bounds);

  // Initial map 
  function initialize() {

    var map;
    var pos;

    // Default pos for map will be center of Manhattan
    if(!pos){
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(40.784148400000000000, -73.966140699999980000);
    }

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13
    };

    getAddress();

    // Draw Map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    map.setCenter(pos);

    // Google Direction text route
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

    //Needed to resize maps 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener (map, 'idle', function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger (map, 'resize');
    });

  }
  // Load Map
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});

/************************************************
    Site Navigational Elements
************************************************/

function toggleSidebar() {
    var state = $('#sidebar').data('toggle');

    if (state == 'hidden') {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').className = "sidebar-appear";
    $('#sidebar').data('toggle', 'shown');
    }
  else if (state == 'shown') {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').className = "sidebar-hidden";
    $('#sidebar').data('toggle', 'hidden');
  }
};

function nextSlide() {
  $('#navCarousel').carousel('next');
};

function prevSlide(){
  $('#navCarousel').carousel('prev');
};

/************************************************
    UI Messages
************************************************/

function hideMessage(){
  $('#init-message').hide(1000);
};

function pushMessage (messageType, message) {
  $('#message-container').hide (0);

  if (messageType == 'error') {
    document.getElementById('message-container').className = "alert alert-danger";
    document.getElementById('icon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign";
  }
  else if (messageType == 'success') {
     document.getElementById('message-container').className = "alert alert-success";
     document.getElementById('icon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign";
  }
  else if (messageType == 'warn') {
      document.getElementById('message-container').className = "alert alert-warning";
      document.getElementById('icon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-exclaimation-sign";
  }
  else {
    //Congrats. Senpai has noticed your ability to break shit. Rejoice.
    console.error ("Please check your messageType.")
  }

  $('#message').text(message);
  $('#message-container').show (1000);
};

/************************************************
    Information Retrieval
************************************************/

// Get current location button function
function getAddress(callback){
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // If geolocation available, get position
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {timeout:60000,maximumAge:60000});
  }
  //Else, browser doesn't support geolocaiton
  else {
    pushMessage ('error', 'Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    console.log("Browser doesn't support geolocaiton");
  }
  // Optional callback
  if (callback){
    callback();
  }
};

function successCallback(position){
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  //Reverse geocoding for current location
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results.length != 0) {
        currentAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
};

function errorCallback(){

};

fillAddress = function() {
  if (currentAddress != 'placeholder') {
    $('#start').val (currentAddress);  
    pushMessage ('success', "Got your current location!");
  }
  else {
    pushMessage ('warn', 'Please share your location to use this feature.');
  }
};

// Set route and request direction result 
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

  if (start == '' && end == '') {
    pushMessage ('error', "Please fill in your current location and destination.");
    start='';
    end='';
    return;
  }
  else if (start == '') {
    pushMessage ('error', "Please fill in your current location.");
    start='';
    end='';
    return;
  }
  else if (end == '') {
    pushMessage ('error', "Please fill in your destination.");
    start='';
    end='';
    return;
  }
  else {
    start += ' new york city';
    end += ' new york city';
  }

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
  };

  deleteTabs();

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            altRouteCount = response.routes.length;
            savedRoutes = response;

            printRoute (savedRoutes, 0);

      //Move to next slide when directions have been retrieved.
      $('#navCarousel').carousel('next');
      //Disable loading icon pseudocode.
      //$('#loadingIcon').hide(300);
      savedRoutes = response;
    }
    else {
      //If DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND 
      //or DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS
      pushMessage ('error', 'No directions found.');
    }
  });
};

function printRoute (routeObj, routeNo) {
    // Get route object
  var thisRoute = routeObj.routes[routeNo].legs[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < thisRoute.steps.length; i++) {
    // Find all possible transit
    if (typeof thisRoute.steps[i].transit != 'undefined' 
        && thisRoute.steps[i].transit.line.vehicle.type == "SUBWAY") {
        trainTab (thisRoute.steps[i]);
    }
  }
}

//Get details from Maps API json object
function getTransitDetail(obj, tabNo){
    var parent='';
    if (tabNo) {
        parent='div#tab'+tabNo+' ';
    }

  $(parent+'#train').text(obj.transit.line.short_name + " Train");
  $(parent+'#train-stop-depart').text(obj.transit.departure_stop.name);
  $(parent+'#train-stop-end').text(obj.transit.arrival_stop.name);
  $(parent+'#num-stop').text(obj.transit.num_stops + " Stops");
  $(parent+'#arrival_time').text(obj.transit.arrival_time.text);
  $(parent+'#departure_time').text(obj.transit.departure_time.text);
  $(parent+'#distance').text(obj.distance.text);
  $(parent+'#duration').text(obj.duration.text);
};

// Get current time from device
function getTime(){
  var currentdate = new Date(); 
  var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
              + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
              + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
              + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
              + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
              + currentdate.getSeconds();
  return datetime;
};

function makeNewTab() {
    var prevTab = 'tab' + tabCount;
    tabCount++;
    var newTab = 'tab' + tabCount;
    console.log ('New Tab.');

    //Adds tab to nav bar
    $('#routeChange').before('<li><a href="#'+newTab+'" data-toggle="tab">TAG LABEL</a></li>');
    //Adds contents of tab
    $('div.tab-content #'+prevTab).after('<div id="'+newTab+'"></div>');
    $('#'+newTab).addClass("tab-pane");
};

function deleteTabs() {
    var thisTab;

    while (tabCount >= 1) {
        thisTab = 'tab' + tabCount;
        //Remove tab from nav bar
        $('ul#tabs li a[href="#'+thisTab+'"]').remove();
        //Remove contents of tab
        $('#'+thisTab).remove();
        tabCount--;
    }

    tabCount = 1;

    $('#tabs a:first').tab('show');
};

function trainTab (obj) {
    makeNewTab();
    $('ul#tabs li a[href="#tab'+tabCount+'"]').text(obj.transit.line.short_name);
    $('#tab'+tabCount).append (
            '<div id="station-info" class="col-xs-11 col-xs-height col-sm-12 col-sm-height">\
              <p>Station Info:</p>\
              <p id="train"></p>\
            <p id="train-stop-depart"></p>\
            <p id="train-stop-end"></p>\
            <p id="num-stop"></p>\
            <p id="arrival_time"></p>\
            <p id="departure_time"></p>\
            <p id="distance"></p>\
            <p id="duration"></p>\
            <!-- <%= link_to "an article", @station%> -->\
          </div>');
    getTransitDetail (obj, tabCount);
};
```

Is it because of the order of my code? I tried playing around with the order and could not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might set up a jsfiddle example (or something similar)  that demonstrates your problem...

Comment: No, the app I'n trying to run works fine it's just whenever I search for directions, the map loads with the route uncentered. I was trying to setup a jsfiddle but my app contains multiple pages and I don't know how to do set that up.

Comment: please look at one's this jsfiddle link may be help to load map in center "http://jsfiddle.net/q9NTS/7/"

Comment: You've posted a lot of code that probably isn't related to the issue. You obviously toggle the visibility of the element which contains the map, we at least need to know which element it is....post the html too.